# ImportError: No module named base in html5lib

Tags: python, django, importerror, requirements.txt, html5lib

I suddenly can't start may Django server any more, running check:

```
python manage.py check
```

shows to the following error:

```py
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/aym/.virtualenvs/prod_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/aym/.virtualenvs/prod_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/aym/workspace/CompanyP/apps/account/models.py", line 18, in <module>
    from apps.groups.models import SubscriptionGroup
  File "/home/aym/workspace/CompanyP/apps/subscription/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from apps.member.models import Member
  File "/home/aym/.virtualenvs/prod_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bleach/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bleach.linkifier import 
  File "/home/aym/.virtualenvs/prod_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bleach/linkifier.py", line 5, in <module>
    from html5lib.filters.base import Filter
ImportError: No module named base
```

Have you any idea?

Comment: Which `bleach` version arae you using!!?

Comment: the current version is bleach==2.0.0

Comment: what are the changes you made?

Comment: @ReynardAsis I just updated my requirements

Comment: @Aymen Gasmi - How did you resolve this ?

Comment: @ManujRastogi I did as suggested below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your `html5lib` is not compatibale with the `bleach` version. Maybe for some reason you have the latest version of [bleach](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bleach) but not the lastest of html5lib. The version bleach 2.0.0 no longer supports html5lib < 0.99999999 (8 9s). Check [Backwards incompatible changes](https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#version-2-0-march-8th-2017)

I think you have to install the latest html5lib (9 9s).

```
pip install html5lib==0.999999999
```

Comment: Facing same problem . Though i can do `from html5lib.filters.base import Filter`  in django shell but it raises exception while performing actions from webapp. Any idea for this kind of behavior ?

Comment: Can you post your Bleach and html5lib versions!??

Comment: `bleach==2.0.0` and `html5lib==0.999999999` This is working in Django shell but not in webapp at client side

Comment: @ManujRastogi make sureyou update also all packages that depends of html5lib (e.g Weasyprint).

Comment: Its updated . Still facing same problem. Its working on my local but not on production.

Comment: It just confirm that it's configuration problem in your prod environment, try to clean it and reinstall the packages.

Comment: did it twice . no success as such